# Filtering and default value in Reactor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm presently experiencing a really strange and frustrating issue at the moment.
I have some code that is being tested that runs through a reactive call chain containing a series of filtering operations.

As the test runs through the code and a 'false' value is returned, the code still passes through to the next call in the chain instead of just returning.

Since I'm still a 'reactive newbie' I'm figuring I'm probably not doing something incorrectly here in the reactive code chain.

Here is the code:

```
    private Mono<GetCardNumberServiceResponseData> updateCardNumberIfLastFourValidAndShaIsNull(Card card, GetCardNumberServiceResponseData responseData) {
        return Mono.just(responseData)
            .filter(response -> isValidLastFour(card, response))
            .defaultIfEmpty(responseData)
            .filter(response -> shaIsNull(card))
            .defaultIfEmpty(responseData)
            .flatMap(response -> updateCardNumber(card, response));
    }
```

This is the portion that's not evaluating correctly:

```
.filter(response -> isValidLastFour(card, response))
```

This is what 'isValidLastFour' currently looks like:

```
    private boolean isValidLastFour(Card card, GetCardNumberServiceResponseData responseData) {
//      String cardNumberFromResponse = responseData.getCardNumber();
//      String lastFourFromResponse =
//          cardNumberFromResponse.substring(cardNumberFromResponse.length() - 4);
//      return card.getLastFour().equals(lastFourFromResponse);
        return false;
    }
```

So presently I just have it hard-coded to return 'false', but as I step through the test with the debugger, the execution just passes right through as if 'true' is being returned, so I'm really just at a loss at what might be causing this behavior.

As always, any and all help is always greatly appreciated!

Comment: After filtering you have an empty Mono. You can still call methods on an empty Mono - which is why the debugger moves to the next chained call. The next call produces Mono with just one value by calling defaultIfEmpty. You are repeatedly doing this, so both filters have no effect.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Lesiak.
So I guess the question now becomes, how would this call need to change to have the desired effect of returning just the 'responseData' object?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a 'returnIfEmpty(V some value)' but I'm not seeing it in the API docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `responseData` to be the default value, in case there is an empty Mono, you have to put `defaultIfEmpty` at the end of the chain:

```java
 return Mono.just(responseData)
        .filter(response -> isValidLastFour(card, response))
        .filter(response -> shaIsNull(card))
        .flatMap(response -> updateCardNumber(card, response))
        .defaultIfEmpty(responseData);
```

Even better, you can merge those filters:

```java
 return Mono.just(responseData)
        .filter(response -> isValidLastFour(card, response) && shaIsNull(card))
        .flatMap(response -> updateCardNumber(card, response))
        .defaultIfEmpty(responseData);
```

Comment: Wow...you rock sir or madem! This absolutely worked! Thank you very, very, much! I had been racking my brain on this and searching the web for examples and a solution for days! I'd like to buy you a beer someday! Cheers! :)

Comment: @lukederienzo were you aware of the operator choosing FAQ in the reference guide of Reactor? https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator

Comment: @SimonBaslé Oh no I wasn't! Thank you!